# Combining code coverage statistics in Teamcity

Tags: javascript, c#, teamcity, code-coverage

**How can I combine multiple code coverage reports to tie in with Teamcity's code coverage statistics?**

I have Grunt pipeline that does Javascript code coverage reporting (using [karma-coverage](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage)) and C# code coverage reporting (using [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) and [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator)). Both offer a multitude of reporting functionality.

For Javascript I am currently doing this:

- HTML report
- **Teamcity-interpretable console output** - see [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) for details
- Text summary

For C#:

- HTML report
- XML report
- **My own Teamcity-interpretable console output using the ReportGenerator interfaces**

I am running my pipeline in Teamcity and want to use the nice Teamcity coverage statistics. It works well for one of the reports using the console output. But Teamcity does not merge them, the next coverage reporter (C# comes after Javascript for me) overwrites the previous report.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Most important things were covered by this setup, this would have been the cherry on top.

Comment: Shame, thanks for getting back to me!